# WPF Clear Validation error programatically using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a PasswordBox in which I have customized to accept validation errors on user input. I use a radio button to enable the password button to allow user input and another radio box to disable it and clear any input information. I have another field that is controlled in exactly the same manner but is a textbox so I am using the following code to disable validation errors in it once the disable radio button has been checked:
 `Validation.ClearInvalid(Username.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty));`

If I wanted to clear validation errors in my PasswordBox how could I do this in a similar manner.

Thanks Callum

Comment: If you use MVVM pattern view validation can be bound to model property. Then just clear errors in model.

Answer (score 0):

The `PasswordBox` has no password property due to security issues (the held vale could be read from the memory). If You want to use the property, You can create an Attached Property, written in this article: [Password Attached Property](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html) but this is not the secure way to go. Password value should be queried once then immediately passed to the target that needs the credentials.
If You use the Attached Property as `GetBindingExpression`, it should work, but I did not try it myself.